# Changing of values of keys in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, mongodb

I have an application, where I use MongoDB, Express and MongoDB. On server side I received data by using find in such look - array of objects(JSON), which is named upProbations. For example, I find information about Max:

```
[        
  {
        Name: 'Max',
        DateOne: 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
        DateTwo: 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z,
        Info: 'Cheerful'
  }
]
```

I want to change information a bit - fields DateOne and DateTwo. They have both types Date and I want to leave only **2019-01-01** and same for DateTwo, so i don't need time(hour, minute, second). The result should look like this:

```
[        
  {
        Name: 'Peter',
        DateOne: 2019-01-01,
        DateTwo: 2019-04-01,
        Info: 'Cheerful'
  }
]
```

This result I will futher use for antoher calculations. I have tried such code, but it's not working:

```
upProbations = upProbations.map(function(a) {
    a.DateOne = a.DateOne.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substr(0, 10);
return a;
})
console.log(upProbations);
```

In which way I can do this?

Comment: So you want to turn them from fields of type Date to fields of type string, where the string only shows the year-month-day? Note that the `startProb` property does not exist on those objects. Did you mean `DateOne` and `DateTwo`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yeah, I want exactly what you said and I mean DateOne and DateTwo, I will edit it)

Comment: Your code works, you just need to access the proper property names on the object...

Comment: @CertainPerformance seeing results in console.log give me the same result without changing anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let upProbations = [
  {
    Name: "Max",
    DateOne: 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    DateTwo: 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z,
    Info: "Cheerful",
  },
];

upProbations = upProbations.map((eachObject) => {
  const { DateOne, DateTwo, Name, Info } = eachObject;
  return {
    Name,
    DateOne: DateOne.toString().split("T")[0],
    DateTwo: DateTwo.toString().split("T")[0],
    Info,
  };
});

console.log(upProbations);
```

Comment: Here is one problem: I can't split DateOne, i receive an error that is not a function

Comment: that split is not a function shows up, when you are applying split method on something that is not a string, by using toString() method, just making sure that you are apllying split method on a string

Comment: Yeah, thank you for help, even the better variant is toISOString().

Comment: your initial data already has ISOString for DateOne and DateTwo

Comment: Oh okay. No problem!